# leaflet.js stops certain events from propagating

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet

I have a problem where my `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mouseover` and `mouseout` events get swallowed and do not fire.

Basically there's a map on my page which I add markers (divIcons) and draw paths on. Separate from this map, I have a tooltips and context menus that attach to events on the various markers and paths in order to be activated. The map does not know anything about the tooltips or context menu so the events are attached by a configuration file that uses jquerys `on` method.

Assuming the divIcons have the class `markerElement` the code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.markerElement', function(){ console.log('ENTER'); });
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.markerElement', function(){ console.log('LEAVE'); });
```

I've tracked the problem down to the **stopPropagation method on line 6484 of leaflet-src.js version 0.7.3**. If I comment out `e.stopPropagation()` my events work, I'm a little confused to the purpose of this method in relation to leaflet.

Is there any other way I can get the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to attach to dynamically created elements on the map without the map knowing about it and without changing the leaflet source?

The context menu and tooltip code works on other elements that are not on the map, so a general solution that can dynamically pick out elements based on some kind of selector would be ideal.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's an option for you to disable all events on `L.Marker` and `L.Path`, you can do that by using `'clickable': false` in their options.

It's also possible to disable only certain events by creating a custom marker extended from `L.Marker`, here i commented out the `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
L.CustomMarker = L.Marker.extend({

  _initInteraction: function () {

        if (!this.options.clickable) { return; }

        // TODO refactor into something shared with Map/Path/etc. to DRY it up

        var icon = this._icon,
            events = ['dblclick', 'mousedown', /*'mouseover', 'mouseout',*/ 'contextmenu'];

        L.DomUtil.addClass(icon, 'leaflet-clickable');
        L.DomEvent.on(icon, 'click', this._onMouseClick, this);
        L.DomEvent.on(icon, 'keypress', this._onKeyPress, this);

        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            L.DomEvent.on(icon, events[i], this._fireMouseEvent, this);
        }

        if (L.Handler.MarkerDrag) {
            this.dragging = new L.Handler.MarkerDrag(this);

            if (this.options.draggable) {
                this.dragging.enable();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Here's an example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/naWEPz?p=preview

If you want to remove the stopPropagation on `L.Marker`'s clickevent you can do so also by extending `L.Marker` in a similar way:

```
L.CustomMarker = L.Marker.extend({

    _onMouseClick: function (e) {
        var wasDragged = this.dragging && this.dragging.moved();

        /*if (this.hasEventListeners(e.type) || wasDragged) {
            L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
        }*/

        if (wasDragged) { return; }

        if ((!this.dragging || !this.dragging._enabled) && this._map.dragging && this._map.dragging.moved()) { return; }

        this.fire(e.type, {
            originalEvent: e,
            latlng: this._latlng
        });
    }
});
```

Kind of hackish but it's supposed to work, you can do the same with other method in `L.Marker` that calls `stopPropagation`. The same goes for `L.Path`, just extend it with the methods you want to change and i think you're good to go (didn't know how to test this properly, so i didn't :D) Good luck!

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll have a play with it. Although this might make upgrading leaflet more difficult in the future.

Comment: That's absolutely true, but only untill Leaflet hits 1.0 and that's supposed to be soon. It's a little effort but if it saves you from using more libraries/assets or pulling some other weird stunts it's certainly worth it in my opinion. Please drop a comment on know how it pans out. Good luck!

Comment: I've decided to override _fireMouseEvent instead. It works fine and I'm not too concerned about the upgrading leaflet issue. For now its the simplest solution that requires the least code changes. Thanks

Comment: No thanks, always welcome, glad to help, that's what SO is for. Cheers!